# Add/remove jquery logic to buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question:

2 div containers. 1st container have 2 buttons - single & multiple. 2nd container have 4 buttons - item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4.

**Logic needed:**
If button **Single** selected, i can choose only 1 from buttons of item 1, item 2, item 3 or item 4.

If button **Multiple** selected, i can choose multiple items. either 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 items.

selected item will have black colour button. No selected item will have gray colour.

Below are the HTML & JS used. but somehow to multi logic not working.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="select-type">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="single-type">single</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multi-type">Multiple</a>
</div>
<div class="select-item">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Item 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Item 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Item 3</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Item 4</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.select-type a').click(function(){
    $('.select-type a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    if($('.single-type').hasClass('selected')){
        $('.select-item a').removeClass('multiType');
        $('.select-item a').addClass('singleType');
        $('.select-item a.singleType').click(function(){
            $('.select-item a.singleType').addClass('type-deselected');
            $(this).removeClass('type-deselected');
        });
    }
    else if($('.multi-type').hasClass('selected')){
        $('.select-item a').removeClass('singleType');
        $('.select-item a').addClass('multiType');
        $('.select-item a').removeClass('type-deselected');
        $('.select-itema.multiType').click(function(){
            $('.select-item a').addClass('type-deselected');
            $(this).removeClass('type-deselected');
            $(this).addClass('type-selected');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```js
$('.select-type a').click(function() {
  $('.select-type a').removeClass('selected');
  $('.select-item a').removeClass('type-selected').addClass('type-deselected');
  $(this).addClass('selected'); 
});

$('.select-item a').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var multipleAllowed = $('.select-type a.selected').hasClass('multi-type'); 
  var selectedCount = $('.select-item a.type-selected').length; 
  var selected = $this.hasClass('type-selected');
  if (selected) {
    $this.removeClass('type-selected').addClass('type-deselected');
  } else {
    if (selectedCount == 1 && !multipleAllowed) {
      $('.select-item a').not($this).removeClass('type-selected').addClass('type-deselected'); 
      $this.removeClass('type-deselected').addClass('type-selected');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('type-selected').removeClass('type-deselected'); 
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.select-item a,
.select-item a.type-deselected,
.select-type a {
  background-color: grey;
  color: #fff;
}

.select-item a.type-selected,
.select-type a.selected {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-type">
    <a href="#" class="single-type btn">single</a>
    <a href="#" class="multi-type btn">Multiple</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="select-item">
  <a href="#" class="btn type-deselected">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn type-deselected">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn type-deselected">Item 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn type-deselected">Item 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks very much for your help!! it works awesome.. another issue.. On single type if user click, will add "item-selected". Other button have to add class name "item-deselected". Same for multi type as well.

Comment: @TDG see my update above. If I understand your comment correctly, that should get you sorted. If not, let me know

Comment: Sorry boss.. "select-type" add/remove select is ok like previous one. I have to add "select/deselect" only for "select-item"

Comment: Hmm, check the newest update, is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi.. sorry to trouble you again and again boss!! "select-type" have to be like 1st code you provided. No changes in that item.       
Only for "Select-item" for Multi-type, item1 selected means "type-selected" and change other 3 items to "type-deselected". if item1 & item2 selected.. other 2 have to be "type-deselected".

Comment: @TDG no worries, check that update, is that what you mean?

Comment: Almost there boss.. but, On "Multi-type" selected. "item1" clicked class="type-selected" adding correctly. But, "item2, item3, item4" have to add "type-deselected" automatically.  if "item2" clicked, "item1, item3, item4" will add class="type-deselected". item 2 will have "item-selected"

Comment: This one last logic missing in my queries..Very sorry to trouble you

Comment: Nearly there... on load " <a href="#" class="btn type-selected">Item 1</a><a href="#" class="btn type-selected">Item 2</a>" like this. Only on click we need to add "type-deselected". Based Our design,  on load colourful button. on selected button will change to light gray. Thanks for your help

Comment: any updates pls?? have to complete this fix ASAP boss!!

Comment: Thanks.. fixed this problem!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.select-type a').click(function() {
  $('.select-type a').removeClass('selected');//remove selected class on type click
  $('.select-item a').removeClass('selected');//remove selected class on type click
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  if ($('.single-type').hasClass('selected')) {
    $('.select-item').removeClass('multiType').addClass('singleType');
  } else if ($('.multi-type').hasClass('selected')) {
    $('.select-item').removeClass('singleType').addClass('multiType');
  }
});

$('.select-item a').click(function() {

  var check = $(this).parent().hasClass('singleType');
  if (check) {//check if type is single
    if ($('.select-item a').hasClass('selected')) {
      $('.select-item a').removeClass('selected');//if there is selected remove the select class
      $(this).addClass('selected');//add select on click element
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');//add select on click element
    }
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('selected');//add select on click element
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-type">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="single-type">single</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="multi-type">Multiple</a>
</div>
<div class="select-item">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Item 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Item 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Item 3</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn">Item 4</a>
</div>
```

Try this way